# Convert meta content to json?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I am using laravel's sanctum auth and I want to use user info in vue's global components, but it's being stored as a string and I can't access the data easily...

Adding user to header:

```
<meta name="user" content="{{ Auth::user('sanctum') }}">
```

Storing the content to a prototype:

```
Vue.prototype.$user = document.querySelector("meta[name='user']").getAttribute('content');
```

But the problem is that it's just a string: [image: data example]

so getting the id or any other data like this:

```
console.log(this.$user.id);
```

doesn't work

Any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the string to a JSON Object with `JSON.parse()`
change this line:
`Vue.prototype.$user = document.querySelector("meta[name='user']").getAttribute('content')`

to:

`Vue.prototype.$user = JSON.parse(document.querySelector("meta[name='user']").getAttribute('content'))`